# Copying features from if field value is using ModelBuilder

Tags: modelbuilder

I am currently trying to understand ModelBuilder and have decided to break apart a big project into smaller ones to understand how everything works. Currently I am stuck on trying to copy features from an **if field value is** logical tool.

The problem I am having is that I cant seem to copy the features from my true or false values. I've tried using copy features and but it wants an input and does not take the true or false is one. If I just in the point features I am using it will just spit them back out since its just copying those fields.

Does anyone have any ideas on what other tools to use or an input to create?

Comment: Are you using the ModelBuilder of ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model has not done so already, represent your data as a feature layer by applying the MakeFeatureLayer tool. Then select the features you want using either the SelectLayerByLocation or SelectLayerByAttribute tool.

Now when you use the CopyFeatures tool, it will only copy the selected features to the output feature class.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you!